# In R, can I get a redirect URL be returned from a httr:BROWSE statement?

Tags: r, withings

At first, I am not the best programmer, so please excuse me if I ask something stupid.

I have a question about the following code (in language R) which I have written in order to get an authentication code for the [Withings API](https://developer.withings.com/api-reference/#tag/oauth2):

```
library(httr)
my_client_id = "..." #deleted because it is secret
my_redirect_uri = "..." #deleted because it is secret
my_scope="user.activity,user.metrics,user.info"

access_url = "https://wbsapi.withings.net/v2/oauth2"
authorize_url = "https://account.withings.com/oauth2_user/authorize2"

my_response_type = "code"
my_state = "..." #deleted because it is secret

httr::BROWSE(authorize_url, query = list(response_type = my_response_type, 
                                       client_id = my_client_id, 
                                       redirect_uri = my_redirect_uri, 
                                       scope = my_scope, 
                                       state = my_state))
```

This code successfully opens the URL

```
http://%22https://account.withings.com/oauth2_user/account_login?response_type=code&client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&scope=user.activity%2Cuser.metrics%2Cuser.info&state=...&b=authorize2%22
```

where I can enter my e-mail-adress and password. After that, it redirects me to the URL

```
http://.../?code=...&state=...
```

where the first dots are my redirect URL. This gives me the code I need for getting the access token. I have tested the code, i.e. I tried to get an access token with using this code and I was successfull.

The problem is, I have to copy/paste the code from the URL (in my browser) to my POST statement (which I use to get the access token) manually and I would like to automatize that. So I would like to get returned the URL with the code so that I can parse it in order to extract the code. I know how to extract the code if I have the URL, but I have no idea how to avoid the copying/pasting and I am not even sure if it is possible. If it is possible, does anyone have an idea how I could add something to my existing code or how I could change my existing code in order to get the URL with the code (apart from doing it manually)?

I am very happy about any help and I want to say thank you in advance!